# Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, smtp, devise-recoverable

I am trying to reset the password with dynamic email server settings in rails 4 using devise.

```
my_mailer.rb

class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
    helper :application
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
    default template_path: 'devise/mailer' 

    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        # Has been dynamically set in the mailer_set_url_options of application_controller.rb
        # opts[:host] = Setup.email_url
        opts[:address] = Setup.email_address
        opts[:port] = Setup.email_port
        opts[:domain] = Setup.email_domain
        opts[:from] = Setup.email_username
        super
    end
end
```

But getting the same error, what can be the issue any help will be really helpful thank you :)
[image]

Comment: post your smtp configuration here

Comment: @RajarshiDas I added the screenshot just have a look into it. Its actually getting everything something messed up I guess from devise side its not overriding.

Comment: you need to post the environment smtp configuration like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

Comment: Thank u I know that we have to do like that, but I don't want to set it like that my smtp configurations are dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all as per the screenshot

I think you are using Gmail as a provider.

Please go to enviroments file(`development.rb` or `production.rb`). I guess you are using development environment.

Go to the file `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "my.website.com" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'website.com',
    user_name:            'user@website.com',
    password:             'password',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Please refer to [this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail).

Comment: I am really sorry to tell but that's the problem I don't want to use it that way. :(

Comment: what does it mean dynamic ? are you fetching the configuration of service from any api

Comment: In my app itself we will get the configuration and uses that configurations itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Devise but had the same error when trying to Dynamically change the smtp_settings of my application mailer.
In my case the settings came from the database.
The way I made it work is by using `after_action` callback of `ActionMailer`. And to merge the settings for the delivery method of my mail

Here is an example:

```
after_action do
 self.delivery_method = SETTING_FROM_DB.delivery_method
 settings = {
   address: SETTING_FROM_DB.address,
   port: SETTING_FROM_DB.port
   # More setting if needed
   }
 self.mail.delivery_method.settings.merge! settings
end
```